# connect ANDROID Device with XAMPP Server work for some sites , not for all

Tags: android, xampp, connection

I want to open my local website from android device, it work fine for one site , but surprisingly didn't work for another site , don't know what is the problem. 
It says:
**WebPage not available** 
The webpage at http://192.168.x.x/mysite could not be loaded because: 
net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
can help please?

Comment: What do you mean by another site?

Comment: I mean that I have folder for each local website in htdocs in xampp folder, like site1, site2,... it work for one but not work for another

Comment: Well time to give some example urls.

Comment: http://192.168.x.x/site1 work correct, but  http://192.168.x.x/site2 not work . I'm opening these urls on android device browser

Comment: Which language are you using for scripts? And what do you mean with 'not work'?

Comment: server code is written by php, and 'not work' means that it shows error as I post it in the question: WebPage not available The webpage at http://192.168.x.x/mysite could not be loaded because: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: You should call your script directly: `http://192.168.x.x/site2/myscript.php`. Dont leave it to the webserver to invoke the php interpreter with some default script.